# why socket binding in server needs its ip address >

Tags: python, tcp

For a connection is to be made, a bounded socket should be listening for clients. Client needs to know both ip address and port.  For bounding a socket why we need an ip address of the server itself when the program(which listens for clients) itself is running on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Simply because a server has multiple addresses, at least the loopback one at 127.0.0.1 (IP v4) and one per physical network interfaces. For example a corporate proxy has commonly two interfaces, one on the internal network and one on the public one. Most have a third one for the DMZ. Being member of different networks, those interfaces must have different addresses. And it make sense to open some services on only one interface.

But you also can use the ANY address (0.0.0.0 in IPv4) that means to accept connections on any interface.